# Geometry nodes vectors to panel

Tags: node-editor, geometry

I'm wondering how to get geometry nodes vectors to work properly.
I'm using code like this

```
row.prop(activemodifier, '["Input_42"]',  text="Position")
```

This is what it looks like

[image]

I would like to get it to look like this instead.

[image]

I've tried to do it with [0],

```
row.prop(activemodifier, '["Input_42"][0]',  text="Position")
```

but it gives error "rna_uiItemR: property not found: NodesModifier.["Input_43"][0]"

Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Actually I found a solution!

Just have to change the `row.prop` to `col.prop`. For it do draw it differently.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)